# Loading image resource in JavaFX Gradle project fails

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, classpath, classloader

Having converted my project to a Gradle project, I have now run into a problem trying to load image files which I moved to the "resources" directory. They previously resided in a package called "graphics" in the same parent directory as the other packages for the source code and I did not have an issue loading them into an Image as follows:

```
Image logo = new Image("/graphics/sce.png");
```

This was the old project structure:

```
src
|-- graphics
|-- gui
|-- models
|-- utils
```

This is the new structure:

```
├── src
|    └── main
|         ├── java
|         |     └── sce
|         |          └── gui
|         |               └── SplashScreen.java
|         └── resources
|               └── images
|                      └── sce.png
```

I have included SplashScreen.java in the structure as it is the first point at which an image is loaded in the program. I have tried numerous methods of loading the image including the old method above and also the following:

```
Image logo = new Image(...);
1. SplashScreen.class.getResource("/images/sce.png").toExternalForm()
2. SplashScreen.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/images/sce.png").toExternalForm()
3. getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/sce.png")
```

Every attempt produces a NullPointerException, with and without the leading "/" on the path. Moving the image out of the "images" package to the parent "resources" directory also makes no difference, nor does trying to access the resource directory through "(/)resources/images/sce.png".

This is my build.gradle file for reference:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

mainClassName = "sce.gui.MainStage"

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'sce'
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what I have overlooked. For the record, I converted the project by making a new Gradle project and moving the files over, if that would have caused the issue somehow.